# How can get new displayName from Api

Tags: onedrive

I get owner's displayName from   /drive.
but after my changed my displayName on the OneDrive website.
I can't get new displayName from this Api.
How can get new displayName from Api?

Comment: Are you talking about OneDrive Personal or Business?

Comment: OneDrive Personal